# UPDATE TABLE SET (subquery) = '0'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Microsoft SQL Server 2012, Management Studio

I have a need to occasionally update a single row from a table with zero values. The hitch is that there is 250 columns so I don't want to hard code the columns and the column count isn't fixed and could change the next time I run the code.

I have this SQL code that returns the column names I am looking for.

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Id'
    AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'FkId'
    AND COLUMN_Name <> 'Business'
```

What I'd like to do is encapsulate that query as a subquery into an `UPDATE`.

```
SET (subquery) = '0' WHERE [Id] = someid.
```

But I am getting an error attempting this. Seems like I should be able to do this but I still get error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

After trying:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET (SELECT
         COLUMN_NAME
     FROM
        information_schema.columns
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME' 
       AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Id'
       AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'FkId'
       AND COLUMN_Name <> 'Business') = '0'
WHERE 
    Id = '26524'
```

I have looked around and there doesn't seem to be a way to SET (subquery) = 0.

Stumped.

Comment: Column and table names cannot be variables.  Look up dynamics sql.

Comment: Do you want to update all columns other than id,fkid,business to 0

Comment: @Frisbee Kindof what I thought.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Yes, set everything but to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @SqlCmd VARCHAR(MAX) = 'UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET ' +  
STUFF(
(
    SELECT
        ',' + COLUMN_NAME + '=0' 
    FROM
        information_schema.columns
    WHERE 
        TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME' 
        AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Id'
        AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'FkId'
        AND COLUMN_Name <> 'Business'
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'') + ' WHERE SomeWhereCrit=123;'

SELECT @SqlCmd;

--If the select shows the correct command, remove the double minus before EXEC
--EXEC(@SqlCmd);
```

Comment: That does the trick. Stored procedure time for ASP.net Thanks!